# What is the Cordil that Edward Topsell describes?

Tags: zoology, history, reptile

In his "History of four-footed beasts and serpents", Edward Topsell describes a "serpent" called Cordil. Since he lists everything that crawls on the ground as a serpent, regardless of being a reptile, amphibian or even insect, there seems to be a wide array of possibilities.

So far, I couldn't find anything about what the cordil [described here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A42668.0001.001/1:9.23?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) seems to be. Does anybody know more?

Answer (score 2):

Your [link](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A42668.0001.001/1:9.23?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) says:

> [...] whereof the Latines derive or rather borrow their Cordulus, and
>   Cordyla [...].

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordylus) says about this:

> The genus *Cordylus* (*Sauria*: *Cordylidae*) includes a wide variety of small- to medium-sized **spiny lizards** from Africa, collectively called **girdle-tailed** or **girdled lizards**.

[image: Tropical girdled]
<sup>Tropical girdled lizard (*Cordylus tropidosternum*)
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordylus)</sup>